pkgProblemResolver::ResolvebyKeep is looping on package libqt5qml5:amd64
Unsure why this issue has arisen and whether I must perform a fresh install.
I upgraded from Ubuntu 22.04.? to 24.04.1 LTS.
I've begun receiving notifications of the issue with libqt5qml5:amd64.
sudo apt upgrade

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  [removed for simplicity]
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 615 not upgraded.

sudo apt list --upgradable

Listing... Done
...
libqt5qml5/noble 5.15.13+dfsg-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.15.3+dfsg-1]
libqt5qmlmodels5/noble 5.15.13+dfsg-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.15.3+dfsg-1]
...

apt-cache depends libqt5qml5:amd64

libqt5qml5
  Depends: libc6
  Depends: libgcc-s1
  Depends: libqt5core5t64
  Depends: libqt5network5t64
  Depends: libstdc++6
  Depends: <qtbase-abi-5-15-13>
    libqt5core5t64
  Recommends: libgl1
  Recommends: libglx-mesa0
  Suggests: qt5-qmltooling-plugins

apt-cache depends libqt5qmlmodels5

libqt5qmlmodels5
  Depends: libc6
  Depends: libqt5core5t64
  Depends: libqt5qml5
  Depends: libstdc++6
  Depends: <qtbase-abi-5-15-13>
    libqt5core5t64
  Depends: <qtdeclarative-abi-5-15-13>
    libqt5qml5

apt-cache policy libqt5qml5

libqt5qml5:
  Installed: 5.15.3+dfsg-1
  Candidate: 5.15.13+dfsg-1
  Version table:
     5.15.13+dfsg-1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe amd64 Packages
 *** 5.15.3+dfsg-1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status


This is working correctly, doing what you asked it to do. That is, upgrade packages that are already installed.

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 615 not upgraded.

However, you're using apt upgrade, which will not upgrade packages requiring installation of additional new packages. This is likely why it's not allowing the upgrade of 615 packages.
sudo apt dist-upgrade or sudo apt full-upgrade are probably what you need.
Further, if other packages are uninstallable, they may show up in the log as Broken. The following command may reveal broken packages which were installed from an unofficial source, such as a PPA. If they are no longer upgradable, they may need to be removed.
grep ^Broken /var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log
Further, it may be necessary to remove the broken package that won't upgrade, and reinstall it. So sudo apt remove libqt5qml5 - will almost certainly remove a number of application packages, which will need reinstalling afterward.

Thank you for the reply! dist-upgrade returns the same error E: Internal Error, pkgProblemResolver::ResolveByKeep is looping on package libqt5qml5:amd64.

Please add the output of apt-cache policy libqt5qml5 to your question

done, thank you!

Also check the update to my response above, you may be able to identify the broken packages from the log.

No results from the grep.
